# Sorting images with datatables

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have a table where one of its collumn is numbers like 1,2,3,4,5...

I replace each of this number with an image like this:

```
<img src="./assets/img/test{{number}}.png">
```

I am also using python, jinja2 and datatables 1.9.4

I want to sort that collumn with the initial numbers. I tried to add those numbers as img id and img alt, but sorting doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: You are better off throwing together your solution for viewing data in a tabular format.Datatables is an utter waste of time if you want to that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement custom data source sorting. Look at http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#functions_type for help on this. I have created a similar one to the hidden title string function, but instead of using the **title** tag, I'm using the **alt** tag of the images. (*edit*: sorry - there is actually an alt tag sorting function in the documentation)

Unfortunately, I cannot show an example as my code is part of an application that requires user login.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest thing you can use is a span with display:none;

`<td><img src="./img/flags_iso/16/en.png"><span style="display:none;">en</span></td>`

Comment: The span hide text is sorted, this has worked for me,